# Alternative für den Ausdruck "Lighten up!"

Tags: grammar, idiom

> Sam, Entspann dich! Das ist nur ein Hund!
>        Sam, lighten up! It's just a dog!

Gibt es eine Alternative für " Entspann Dich!" ?

Comment: Fragst du nach den Bedeutungen von `Entspann dich!` oder von `Lighten up!`?

Comment: I would like to know if there"s another way to say it. :)

Comment: Yes, but another way for which of the two?

Comment: Entspann Dich  :)

Comment: No, really: you should edit your question (I can't since I don't understand for which of the two you need alternatives).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already proposed, *Entspann dich!* is a possbible translation.

More colloquial alternatives:

- *Komm runter!*
- *Mach dich (mal) locker!*

Comment: `Nimm es nicht so ernst/schlimm!`

Comment: "Lach mal!", "Chill mal!"